# python decorator arguments with @ syntax

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to use a cached property decorator that can take arguments.

I looked at this implementation: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/217241/a-cached-property-decorator

```
from functools import update_wrapper 

def cachedProperty (func ,name =None ):
  if name is None :
    name =func .__name__ 
  def _get (self ):
    try :
      return self .__dict__ [name ]
    except KeyError :
      value =func (self )
      self .__dict__ [name ]=value 
      return value 
  update_wrapper (_get ,func )
  def _del (self ):
    self .__dict__ .pop (name ,None )
  return property (_get ,None ,_del )
```

But the problem I have is that I cannot call the decorator with the @ syntax if I want to use the parameter:

```
@cachedProperty(name='test') # This does NOT work
def my_func(self):
    return 'ok'

# Only this way works
cachedProperty(my_func, name='test')
```

How to use the @ syntax with decorators arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a *decorator factory*, another wrapper that *produces* the decorator:

```
from functools import wraps 

def cachedProperty(name=None):
    def decorator(func):
        if decorator.name is None:
            decorator.name = func.__name__ 
        @wraps(func)
        def _get(self):
            try:
                return self.__dict__[decorator.name]
            except KeyError:
                value = func(self)
            self.__dict__[decorator.name] = value 
            return value 
        def _del(self):
            self.__dict__.pop(decorator.name, None)
        return property(_get, None, _del)
    decorator.name = name
    return decorator
```

Use this as:

```
@cachedProperty(name='test')
def my_func(self):
    return 'ok'
```

A decorator is really just syntactic sugar for:

```
def my_func(self):
    return 'ok'
my_func = cachedProperty(name='test')(my_func)
```

so as long as the expression after `@` returns your decorator <sup>[*]</sup> it doesn't matter what the expression itself actually does.

In the above example, the `@cachedProperty(name='test')` part first executes `cachedProperty(name='test')`, and the return value of that call is used as the decorator. In the above example, `decorator` is returned, so the `my_func` function is decorated by calling `decorator(my_func)`, and the return value of that call is `property` object, so that is what'll replace `my_func`.

---

<sup>[*]</sup> The `@` expression syntax is deliberately limited in how much it is allowed to do. You can do attribute lookups and calls, that's it, the [`decorator` grammar rule](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-decorator) only allows an optional call with arguments at the end of a dotted name (where dots are optional):

> ```
> decorator               ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE)
> ```

This is a [deliberate limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567563/python-decorator-func-attribute-syntax-error/32567701#32567701) of the syntax.

Comment: Yes that does not work, name is not referenced. How can I have access to it then? Also, would it be easier to define the decorator with a class?

Comment: is there a difference between using `(set|get|del)attr` and `__dict__`?

Comment: @rmartinjak: it would bypass any data descriptors, for one. So if there is a `type(self).test` property, `self.__dict__['test']` would access the instance attribute directly without triggering the property.

Comment: once I defined a descriptor with arguments, do I always have to call it with the parentheses even if I want the default values for the arguments ``@cached_property()``? Doing ``@cached_property`` returns the decorator function.

Comment: @YAmikep: yes, because otherwise the `cached_property()` factory would be called with the function-to-decorate.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: Can I go back in time and vote against this decorator syntax? Requiring functions within functions was already bad enough - functions within functions within functions is horrible, not to mention ridiculously non-intuitive. I would never have guessed this syntax for defining a decorator that takes an argument. Ever.