# Python decorator @func().attribute syntax error

Tags: python, class, attributes, decorator, python-decorators

I tried to find an answer here, but could not.

```
@obj.func # works
@obj.func(**kwargs)  #works
@obj.func1(**kwargs).func2   #-> syntax error
```

I do not understand why the third form is a SyntaxError, it seems for me that is not violating any python syntax and it is clear for me what the user want to do (see example below).

I looked at [pep 0318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) of decorator implementation but didn't find any answers.

Here bellow, would be an example of use:

```
class ItemFunc(object):
    def __init__(self, fcall=None, **kwargs):
        self.defaults = kwargs
        self.fcall = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = dict(self.defaults, **kwargs)
        # do something more complex with kwargs 
        output = self.fcall(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something more with output  
        return output

    def caller(self, fcall):
        """ set call and return self """
        self.call = fcall # after some check obviously
        return self

    def copy(self,**kwargs):
        kwargs = dict(self.defaults, **kwargs)
        return self.__class__(self.fcall, **kwargs)

    def copy_and_decorate(self, **kwargs):
        return self.copy(**kwargs).caller
```

Than you can use ItemFunc as a decorator:

```
@ItemFunc
def plot(**kwargs):
    pass

redcross = plot.copy(color="red", marker="+")
@redcross.caller
def plot_data1(**kwargs):
    pass

bluecross = redcross.copy(color="blue")
@bluecross.caller
def plot_data2(**kwargs):
    pass
```

But why this following 'short cut syntax' is forbidden :

```
@redcross.copy(color="blue").caller
def plot_data2(**kwargs):
    pass
```

But I can do:

```
@redcross.copy_and_decorate(color="blue")
def plot_data2(**kwargs):
    pass
```

The first form looks for nicer, at least I understand better the intentions behind.

Answer (score 6):

The [*Function definitions* grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) does not allow for calls with further dotted names; the syntax is limited to dotted names and an optional call *at the end*:

```
decorated      ::=  decorators (classdef | funcdef)
decorators     ::=  decorator+
decorator      ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
funcdef        ::=  "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ":" suite
dotted_name    ::=  identifier ("." identifier)*
```

Note that that's *not* a full expression, but a very limited subset.

This echoes the PEP, which states:

> The decorator statement is limited in what it can accept -- arbitrary expressions will not work. Guido preferred this because of a gut feeling [17] .

and

> The rationale for having a function that returns a decorator is that the part after the @ sign can be considered to be an expression **(though syntactically restricted to just a function)**, and whatever that expression returns is called. See declaration arguments [16] .

Emphasis mine.

The rationale is that [Guido feels there isn't a real use case for allowing more](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-August/046711.html):

> So while it would be quite easy to change the syntax to @test in the
>   future, I'd like to stick with the more restricted form unless a real
>   use case is presented where allowing @test would increase readability.
>   (@foo().bar() doesn't count because I don't expect you'll ever need
>   that).

You'll have to convince Guido and the other core developers that your case is a proper usecase worthy of lifting these restrictions!

Comment: Yep , it is more a philosophical problem. For me finishing the decorator with something like .getter or .caller (like in my example) makes it clear what we want to do, while calling a function that at the end send a .caller method (my example again) is allowed but less readable.  don't you think ?

Comment: @user3240484: I can see where you are going with your setup; but perhaps instead of using an attribute, have `__call__` return the actual decorator, something that also supports `__call__`?

Comment: You are right, but if you look at my example the __call__ method  already act like the decorator of a 'fcall' funtion, to keep the object function-like for users.  I could replace __call__ by a call function  and use the __call__ to return the decorator, but what I gain there I loose it there.  thanks

Comment: Yes, because your class is a decorator factory, decorator *and* wrapper in one. I'm suggesting you pull out the wrapper part. The result of a decoration does not itself need to be useable as a decorator again, should it?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the other answer, [Guido had a "gut feeling"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-August/046711.html) was the reason for the restriction originally.

**This restriction is lifted in Python 3.9.**, allowing decorators to be any valid expression.

[Previously, the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/grammar.html?highlight=decorator) for decorators was:

```
decorator: '@' dotted_name [ '(' [arglist] ')' ] NEWLINE
```

In Python 3.9 [the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/grammar.html?highlight=decorator) is simplified to:

```
decorator: '@' namedexpr_test NEWLINE
```

This is the only grammar change between 3.8 and 3.9. See [PEP 614 -- Relaxing Grammar Restrictions On Decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0614/) for full details.