# Python3 'repeat' decorator with argument: @repeat(n)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, default-parameters

I have seen (a great) many tutorials and snippets of decorators w/ and w/o arguments, including those two I would look consider as canonical answers: [Decorators with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418499/decorators-with-arguments), [python decorator arguments with @ syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271923/python-decorator-arguments-with-syntax), but I don't see why I get an error in my code.

The code below lives in the file `decorators.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Description: decorators
"""
import functools

def repeat(nbrTimes=2):
    '''
    Define parametrized decorator with arguments
    Default nbr of repeats is 2
    '''
    def real_repeat(func):
        """
        Repeats execution 'nbrTimes' times
        """
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            while nbrTimes != 0:
                nbrTimes -= 1
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_repeat
    return real_repeat
```

The first warning I get from my syntax-checker is that `nbrTimes` is an "unused argument".

I tested the above in python3 interactive console with:

```
>>> from decorators import repeat

>>> @repeat(nbrTimes=3)
>>> def greetings():
>>>     print("Howdy")
>>>
>>> greetings()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
  File path/to/decorators.py, line xx in wrapper_repeat
   '''
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nbrTimes' referenced before assignment.
```

I just don't see where I'm bungling it. In other examples the passed parameter (here `nbrTimes`)  was not *"used"* until later in the inner function, so the "unused argument" warning and error upon execution leave me kind of high and dry. Still relatively new to Python. Help much appreciated.

***Edit:*** (in response to [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078288/scope-of-variables-in-python-decorators-changing-parameters) flag by @recnac) 
It is not clear at all what OP in your purported duplicate wanted to achieve. I can only surmise that he/she intended to have access to a  counter  defined inside a decorator's wrapper, from global scope, and failed to declare it as `nonlocal`. Fact is we don't even know whether OP dealt with Python 2 or 3, although it is largely irrelevant here.  I concede to you that the error messages were very similar, if not equivalent, if not the same. However my intent was not to access a in-wrapper-defined counter from global scope. I intended to make this counter purely local, and did. My coding errors were elsewhere altogether. It turns out the excellent discussion and solution provided by Kevin (below) are of a nature, totally different from just adding a `nonlocal <var>` inside the wrapper definition block (in case of Python 3.x). I won't be repeating Kevin's arguments. They are limpid and available to all.

Finally I go out on a limb and will say that the error message is perhaps the least important of all here, even though it is clearly a consequence of my bad code. For that I make amends, but this post is definitely not a rehash of the proposed "duplicate".

Comment: Aside: code is easier to read when its style is consistent. Calling something `nbrTimes` in otherwise PEP 8 formatted code is visually jarring. Consider renaming that to `nbr_times`, `number_of_times` or even just `times`.

Comment: @Chris; Sorry, I am new to this. I didn't even know that there were conventions of that sort. I tend to use whatever ink I find in my pen at time of writing. Tx for the heads-up ...

Comment: You're welcome, Cbhihe. For completeness, here's a link to PEP 8 (Python's official style guide): https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. You don't _have to_ follow that guide, but most Python developers do. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proposed duplicate question, [Scope of variables in python decorators - changing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12078288/953482) gives useful information that explains why `wrapper_repeat` considers `nbrTimes` to be a local variable, and how `nonlocal` might be used to make it recognize the `nbrTimes` defined by `repeat`. This would fix the exception, but I don't think it's a complete solution in your case. Your decorated function will still not repeat.

```
import functools

def repeat(nbrTimes=2):
    '''
    Define parametrized decorator with arguments
    Default nbr of repeats is 2
    '''
    def real_repeat(func):
        """
        Repeats execution 'nbrTimes' times
        """
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal nbrTimes
            while nbrTimes != 0:
                nbrTimes -= 1
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_repeat
    return real_repeat

@repeat(2)
def display(x):
    print("displaying:", x)

display("foo")
display("bar")
display("baz")
```

Result:

```
displaying: foo
displaying: bar
```

"foo" and "bar" are each displayed only one time, and "baz" is displayed zero times. I assume this is not the desired behavior.

The first two calls to `display` fail to repeat because of the `return func(*args, **kwargs)` inside your `while` loop. The return statement causes `wrapper_repeat` to terminate immediately, and no further iterations of the `while` will occur. So no decorated function will repeat more than once. One possible solution is to remove the `return` and just call the function.

```
import functools

def repeat(nbrTimes=2):
    '''
    Define parametrized decorator with arguments
    Default nbr of repeats is 2
    '''
    def real_repeat(func):
        """
        Repeats execution 'nbrTimes' times
        """
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal nbrTimes
            while nbrTimes != 0:
                nbrTimes -= 1
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_repeat
    return real_repeat

@repeat(2)
def display(x):
    print("displaying:", x)

display("foo")
display("bar")
display("baz")
```

Result:

```
displaying: foo
displaying: foo
```

"foo" is being displayed twice, but now neither "bar" nor "baz" appear. This is because `nbrTimes` is shared across all instances of your decorator, thanks to `nonlocal`. once `display("foo")` decrements `nbrTimes` to zero, it remains at zero even after the call completes. `display("bar")` and `display("baz")` will execute their decorators, see that `nbrTimes` is zero, and terminate without calling the decorated function at all.

So it turns out that you don't *want* your loop counter to be nonlocal. But this means you can't use `nbrTimes` for this purpose. Try creating a local variable based on `nbrTimes`' value, and decrement that instead.

```
import functools

def repeat(nbrTimes=2):
    '''
    Define parametrized decorator with arguments
    Default nbr of repeats is 2
    '''
    def real_repeat(func):
        """
        Repeats execution 'nbrTimes' times
        """
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            times = nbrTimes
            while times != 0:
                times -= 1
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_repeat
    return real_repeat

@repeat(2)
def display(x):
    print("displaying:", x)

display("foo")
display("bar")
display("baz")
```

Result:

```
displaying: foo
displaying: foo
displaying: bar
displaying: bar
displaying: baz
displaying: baz
```

... And while you're at it, you may as well use a `for` loop instead of a `while`.

```
import functools

def repeat(nbrTimes=2):
    '''
    Define parametrized decorator with arguments
    Default nbr of repeats is 2
    '''
    def real_repeat(func):
        """
        Repeats execution 'nbrTimes' times
        """
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(nbrTimes):
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_repeat
    return real_repeat

@repeat(2)
def display(x):
    print("displaying:", x)

display("foo")
display("bar")
display("baz")
```

Comment: _[Python 3.7.3 on Arch]_ -- Still have an issue with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nbrTimes' referenced before assignment`. It is the exact same error as before with code copied/pasted from directly above ... I think the difference derive from my calling `from decorators, import repeat` in the console instead of having it all in one script as is your case (I assume). I start the console from the same directory where decorators.py is located. Could it be a PYTHONPATH issue ?

Comment: I tried: `@repeat()`, `@repeat(3)`, `@repeat(nbrTimes=4)` and finally `@repeat`, followed by function definition and function call... I did not expect the latter to work properly. None did.  :-|

Comment: Strange, I would expect my final code block to work even if you imported it into the console. `local variable 'nbrTimes' referenced before assignment` should be impossible, since I never have `nbrTimes` on the left hand side of an assignment. I suspect that your code is somehow referencing an older version of your `decorators` module. I suggest closing the console and opening a brand new one. It may also help to rename your `decorators` file.

Comment: `@repeat` and `@repeat(3)` and `@repeat(nbrTimes=4)` should all work. I expect `@repeat` to run without crashing, but it won't actually call the decorated function.

Comment: +1 All is well, Kevin tx very much for the gentle, baby step-by-baby step explanation. What is strange though is I **did** re-issue `from decorators import repeat` at every change and vim buffer-write of `decorators.py`, but my console session did not take that into account. It stuck with the initial import of the buggy decorator definition. (Just checked the sequence of cmds I issued in console history and the console just did not re-import.) Not the behavior I expected...