# Most pythonic way to try, except, and retry once

Tags: python

I'm looking for the most pythonic way of trying a command, catching if an error occurs and retrying by running a preparatory command and then the original command. Specifically in my case I'm looking to write a table to a database, catch if a "schema does not exist" error is thrown, then trying to create a schema and retrying the write table. Then, if the write table errors again I don't want to catch it.

So far I have (schematically):

```
try:
    write_to_table(table, schema)
except sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
    create_schema(schema)
    write_to_table(table, schema)
```

This does what I want, but seems a bit off somehow, maybe because I'm duplicating write_to_table().

So what's the most pythonic way of doing the above?

P.S. When I say I'd like to retry, I do NOT want something like this: [How to retry after exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083987/how-to-retry-after-exception/2083996#2083996)

Comment: That seems like the most straight forward way to do it…

Comment: Why don't you first call create_schema (if doesn't exists) and then call write_to_table within try block ?

Comment: You could use the retrying library which is handy enough. Or you could take the retry logic from there and do a custom implementation. https://pypi.org/project/retrying/

Comment: @Nair maybe a minor point, but most of the times the schema is there. So in your solution, most of the times you're sending an extra command to the DB which will fail.

Comment: @pythonicpete, call create_schema (if doesn't exists)

Comment: @Nair how do I find out whether the schema exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a reusable decorator !!

```
def retry(func):
        '''
        Decorator.
        If the decorated function fails with an exception 
        calls it again after a random interval.
        '''
        def _retry(*args,**kwargs):
            max_retries = 1
            for i in range(max_retries):
                try:
                    value = func(*args,**kwargs)
                    return value
                except sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError as e:
                    print('function:[{}({},{})] Failed with error: {} . Retrying...'.format(func.__name__,str(*args),str(kwargs),str(e)))
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(1,3))
            print("Max_retries({}) exceeded for function {}".format(max_retries,func.__name__))
        return _retry
```

By using the above decorator, in which you can also configure the number of retriesand the retry interval, you can do the following:

```
@retry
write_to_table(table, schema)
```

Comment: you could also pass the number of retries as an argument, e.g. shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55794627/10197418). but why the `time.sleep`?

Comment: ofcourse you can pass it as argument. The time.sleep can be used in case you are trying to execute a function that fails due to a race condition, if thats not the case you can just remove it.

Comment: This doesn't execute `create_schema` in case of a failure…

Comment: I specifically linked to something like this as the thing I don't want.

Comment: Yes, that's why the proposed pythonic way is to wrap the functionality inside a decorator.